# Is there a program which shows set equality in steps?

Tags: ring-theory, boolean-ring

> To show:
>
> $(P(M),+,\cdot)$ is a commutative ring.
>
> $A+B:= (A\cup B) \backslash (A\cap B)$ (or XOR)
>
> $A\cdot B:=A\cap B$

First Ring axiom:

Addition is assiociative

$(A+B)+C=A+(B+C)$ for all $A,B,C\in P(M)$

Let $x\in ((A+B)+C)$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (((A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B))+C)$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (((((A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)) \cup C) \backslash (((A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)) \cap C)))$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (?)$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (?)$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (?)$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (?)$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (((A \cup ((B \cup C) \backslash (B \cap C))) \backslash (A \cap ((B \cup C) \backslash (B \cap C)))))$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (A+((B \cup C) \backslash (B \cap C)))$

$\Leftrightarrow x\in (A+(B+C))$

Is there a program which can solve such things with steps to follow?

This is just tedious.

Or is my way in general stupid?

Comment: The hardest part is to show that "+" is associative. I you know spanish you can check this link: https://blocdemat.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/una-prueba-elegante-de-la-asociatividad-de-la-diferencia-simetrica/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$+$ is $\oplus$, which is the exclusive or.  Some identities for XOR are:

$$X\oplus Y = (X\cup Y)\cap (X\cap Y)^\complement= (X\cap Y^\complement)\cup(X^\complement\cap Y)\\ (X\oplus Y)^\complement = (X\oplus Y^\complement)=(X^\complement\oplus Y)=(X\cap Y)\cup(X^\complement\cap Y^\complement)$$

Then $(A+B)+C\\ = ((A\oplus B)\cup C)\cap ((A\oplus B)^\complement\cup C^\complement)\\= ((A\cap B^\complement)\cup (A^\complement\cap B)\cup C)\cap ((A\oplus B)^\complement\cup C^\complement) \\= ((A\cap B^\complement)\cup (A^\complement\cap B)\cup C)\cap ((A\cap B)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\cup C^\complement) \\ = (A\cap B\cap C)\cup(A\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B\cap C^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C)$

By symmetry, then $(A+B)+C=A+(B+C)$

---

(Sigh) Like so $A+(B+C)\\ = (A\cup (B\oplus C))\cap (A^\complement\cup(B\oplus C)^\complement)\\= (A\cup(B\cap C^\complement)\cup (B^\complement\cap C))\cap (A^\complement\cup(B\oplus C)^\complement) \\= (A\cup(B\cap C^\complement)\cup (B^\complement\cap C))\cap (A^\complement\cup(B\cap C)\cup(B^\complement\cap C^\complement)) \\ = (A\cap B\cap C)\cup(A\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B\cap C^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C)$

The exclusive-disjunction of three sets consists of: everything that is *either* in exactly any one of the three sets, *or* in the union of all three sets.

Comment: Do you consider that beginner stuff at university math, or a little advanced? And why can we argue here with symmetry? Sorry if that question sounds dull. (actually if that's advanced stuff you don't need to explain it, i wouldn't grasp it probably)

Comment: It's junior highschool level.  And we can argue symmetry because $\cap,\cup$ are both commutative (and so too is $\oplus$), and thus the last line is symmetrical for placement of tokens.

Comment: I think i grasp your proof now. The intersection between all 3 sets, and also all possible combinations of the others will appear finally, if we resolve the right hand side. Therefore they are the same, even without doing it.